# Search/replace name from a relative URL

Tags: sed, grep, vi

I have a file containing entries of the form:

```
"/application/device/android/device-id", "/application/device/ios/device-id", "/application/device/windows/device-id"
```

I want to simplify the above automatically by removing the part `/application/device` and the last part `/device-id`.

When this is done, the file, potentially containing thousands of entries, would contain the patterns:

```
android, ios, windows
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use awk:

```
awk -F"/" '{print $4,$8,$12}' filename
```

or for use comma as separator:

```
awk  'BEGIN {FS="/"; OFS=", ";} {print $4,$8,$12}' filename
```

if u have more than 3 string like this, use for in awk:

```
awk  'BEGIN {FS="/";} {for(i=4;i<=NF-4;i+=4) printf "%s",$i" ,"} END {last=int(NF/4)*4; print $last }' filename
```

Answer (score 1):

***sed*** approach:

```
sed 's~/application/[^/]*/\([^/]*\)/device-id~\1~g' file
```

The output (for your current test file):

```
"android", "ios", "windows"
```

Comment: You certainly answer my question so well! The only thing is what if the device part, "device", can be one dynamic word? For instance it can be abcdef or abc-def. Sorry, my fault!

Comment: @user1721180, if **device** section will be dynamic - use my updated expression

Answer (score 0):

With shell parameter expansion:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    printf '%s\n' "${line//@(\"\/application\/device\/|\/device-id\")}"
done < infile
```

This requires the `extglob` shell option to enable the `@(pattern1|pattern2)` pattern.

The expansion used is of the form `${parameter//pattern/string}`, which replaces all instances of *`pattern`* with *`string`* – in our case the empty string, so `/string` was skipped.